# if $ S(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n,|x|<R$, $S_k(R)$ bounded,prove or disprove $\lim\limits_{x\to R}S(x)$ exist?

Tags: limits, power-series

> let $$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n,a_{n}>0,|x|<R$$
>   (or mean that powr series have radius of convergence R.)
>
> and let $$S_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}x^k=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+\cdots+a_{n}x^n$$
>   if  $S_{n}(R)$ is bounded,mean that there exsit constant $M>0$,such
>   $$|S_{n}(R)|<M$$

**prove or disprove $$\lim_{x\to R}S(x)$$
is exsit.**?

I guess this is right,and I can't prove it.Thank you.

**By the way:** I have add this condition $a_{n}>0$.then I can't

Comment: It appears be a generalization of Theorem 8.3, Baby Rudin.

Comment: Hello,@Martín-BlasPérezPinilla,the Rudin book theorem 8.3 is this: Give a double sequence $\{a_{ij}\}$ suppose that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_{ij}|=b_{i}$,and $\sum b_{i}$ conberges,then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$

Comment: Sorry, fat fingers. The previous theorem, 8.2.

Comment: oh,But this problem is $|x|<R$,so we can't prove obtain $$f(x)=(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_{n}x^n$$,where $s_{n}=a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n}$,Thank you

Comment: It can converge e.g. $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ or just oscillates e.g $a_n = (-1)^n$ w/o converging to anything.

Comment: @achillehui,Hello,Just oscillates e.g $a_{n}=(-1)^nw/0$? what is $w$ and $o$? Thank you

Comment: @chinamath, should be w/o, shorthand for without.

Comment: sorry,I don't understand,and you mean my problem is not true? Thank you

Comment: Assume $R>0$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}R^n$ converge then $\lim_{x\to R^{-}}S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}R^n$

Comment: @Julien,How prove this ?Thank you

Comment: It's true if the $a_n$ are positive but are you sure it is true in general ?

Comment: actually achille had the solution, $a_n=(-1)^n$ is a counter-example...

Comment: @YannHamdaoui I think he wants to prove our statement (see my comment).

Comment: @chinamath If the $a_n$ are positive, then the partial sums at $x=R$ are increasing, and boundedness implies convergence trivially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you know that if $|S_n(R)|<M$ and $a_n>0$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nR^n$ is convergent. If $R=1$, This is Theorem 8.2 of Baby Rudin and for arbitrary $R$ you can see following Theorem that you only need to define $g(x)=S(Rx)-S(R)$.

**Complex Version of Abel's Limit Theorem.** Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ have radius of convergence $R$ and let $z_0\in\mathbb C$ with $|z_0|=R$ where the series $f(z_0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz_0^n$ converges. Then
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=f(z_0)$$
where the limit on the left is taken in such a way that $|z|<R$ and that the ratio $\frac{|z_0-z|}{R-|z|}$ remains bounded by a fixed constant.

**Some part of proof that you need.** By considering the limit of the function $$\color{red}{g(z)=f(z_0z)-f(z_0)}$$
as $z\to1$ in such a way that $|z|<1$ and that the ratio $\frac{|1-z|}{1-|z|}$ remains bounded by a fixed constant, we may henceforth assume that $z_0=1$ and that $f(z_0)=0$.

With these assumptions, if we put $s_n=a_0+a_1+...+a_n$, then $0=f(1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\lim s_n$. Now observe that $a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}$, so
$$\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k=(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^ns_kz^k+s_nz^n$$
Since $s_n\to0$ and $|z|<1$ it follows that $s_nz^n\to0$. Therefore, Taking $n\to\infty$, we obtain
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n=(1-z)\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_nz^n.$$

Comment: Ah, duh, I overlooked the condition $a_n > 0$ in the question. Then boundedness of the partial sums of course implies convergence and hence uniform convergence of the power series on the closed disk.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ and $L=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kR^k$.
From $a_k\ge0$, for every $n$ and $0<x<R$ we have
$$ S_n(x) \le  S(x) \le L. $$
From fixed $n$ and $x\to R-0$ you get
$$ S_n(R) =\lim_{x\to R-0} S_n(x) \le \liminf_{x\to R-0} S(x) \le \limsup_{x\to R-0} S(x) \le L. $$
Then, from $n\to\infty$,
$$ L=\lim_{N\to\infty} S_n(R) \le \liminf_{x\to R-0} S(x)\le \limsup_{x\to R-0} S(x) \le L. $$
Therefore $\liminf\limits_{N\to\infty} S(R) = \limsup\limits_{x\to R-0} S(x) =L$, so 
$\lim\limits_{x\to R-0} S(x)$ exists and $\lim\limits_{x\to R-0} S(x)=L=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kR^k$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to Abel's continuity theorem. The function $S(x)$ is continuous in its convergence set; in particular if the series converges at $R$ then $S(x)$ is continuous at $R-0$.